# How do I write sqoop database command?

Tags: linux, sqoop

Is there a different command other than --database? 
Reference: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server

Command 1 works!

```
sqoop import  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=customers;username=blah;password=blah"
```

Comand 2 does NOT work.

```
sqoop import  --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost --database=customers --username blah --password blah
```

My goal is to split Command 1 into multiple codes. What am I doing wrong in command 2 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an argument that doesn't exist: `--database`. Why not try:

```
sqoop import  --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=customers" --username blah --password blah
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Figured problem that was giving the error. --database doesn't exist. I am also running in Ooozie workflow, which makes the syntax of sqoop vs. oozie vs command line little bit different. Command 2 will not work. If you put the command 1, and remove quote from oozie, it runs just fine and loads the data.